# Combobox SelectionChanged event not seen?

Tags: c#, windows, combobox, microsoft-metro, selectionchanged

In a Windows 8 Metro application, I have a Combobox and I would like to call a method every time I select something else from the list.

I have my Method, and with *ValueChanged="MyMethod"* of a Slider, it works fine.

However, when i try with a combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Mentality" SelectedValue="Item1" SelectionChanged="MyMethod" >
                <x:String>Item1</x:String>
                <x:String>Item2</x:String>
                <x:String>Item3/x:String>
```

I have this error:

> No overload for 'MyMethod' matches delegate 
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler'

Comment: Is MyMethod public and have you passed the event argument as well as the source argument in the method signature?

Comment: Show the method declaration for MyMethod()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueChanged` and `SelectionChanged` have different signatures.  You can't use the same handler for both.

To wire up to `SelectionChanged`, you would need a method like this:

```
void MyMethod(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```